# Sync Time via ssh with remote Linux Server

Tags: linux, bash, date

i want to get the time of a remote server and set that date on my pc. I tried that with the following bash script: (yes, i need to substract 39 years from server year)

[code]

```sh
#!/bin/bash
NOW=$(sshpass -p "password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@serverip -t "date -d '-39 year' '+%Y-%m-%d %T'")
date $NOW
```

Unfortunately, i get the error:

```
date: extra operand '20:42:37\\r'
```

I think the problem is the return. I tried to remove the \r with sed and tr, but it did not work at all. Who can help me?

Comment: date expects a single operand.  You are giving an invalid format with a space in the middle.

Comment: Remove `-t`, why it's there.

Comment: I updated my script, but it does not work:


```#!/bin/bash
NOW=$(sshpass -p "password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server "date -d '-39 year'")
# '+%Y-%m-%d %T'")
date -s $NOW
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
NOW=$(sshpass -p "password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@serverip "date -d '-39 year' '+%Y-%m-%d %T'")
date "$NOW"
```

You have **two** problems in your script:

1. `-t` introduces a <kbd>carriage return</kbd> into the variable
2. You need to quote the variable, `"$NOW"`

Comment: Now i get:
date: invalid date '1983-03-31 13:02:07'
date: invalid date 'Thu Mar 31 13:02:39 CEST 1983'

//E: Works with date -s
Thank you!

Comment: What OS are you running this from?  Not the server end, the machine that script runs on.  And can you please `echo $NOW` and add it to your question? @proc